# JQ - filter value with space

Tags: json, jq

I want to select a value and filter it. But it has a space. And I'm trying to do this using a for loop.
But it doesn't return any output when using a `for loop`. I even tried `--arg name "$i"` but that didn't work either.

The values are "dummy group 1", "dummy group 2"

```
group_list=("dummy group 1", "dummy group 2");

for i in "${group_list[@]//,/}"
do

echo $groupid_json | jq  -r '.result[] | select(.name == "$i") | .groupid'

done
```

But nothing happens.
Here is the actual json output that I'm trying to filter:

```
[
  {
    "groupid": "92",
    "name": "dummy group 1"
  },
  {
    "groupid": "93",
    "name": "dummy group 2"
  }
]
```

If I type the value then it works

```
echo $groupid_json | jq  -r '.result[] | select(.name == "dummy group 1") | .groupid'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `group_list` properly and it'll work.

```
group_list=("dummy group 1" "dummy group 2")
for i in "${group_list[@]}"; do
  jq -r --arg name "$i" '.[] | select(.name == $name) .groupid' <<< $groupid_json
done
```

Comment: I had to use command because I have another JQ that does `echo ${group_list[@]} | jq -R 'split (", ")')` and then passe it to `--argjson`. Maybe I need to fix that but that doesn't work properly with group name with space. I'll see what I can do.. Is there no way to get it working when using `comma`? Because `echo $i` returns correct value

Comment: @R0bert2 you didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: yea sorry about that. I think it makes sense now. I'll use the proper array and try and fix the `--jsonarg` issue